# Terraform and S3 - How to upload files to an existing bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

How do you upload files to an existing s3 bucket(created out of terraform infrastructure) without destroying contents of bucket or re-creating bucket.

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket = "terraformtests"
    key    = "terraformstate.tf"
    region = "us-east-1"
  }
}


resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "terraformtests" {
  bucket = "terraformtests"
  key    = "test/prod/1000/keys"
  source = "deploy"
  etag   = "${md5(file("keys"))}"

}
```

This is what i have. It runs fine in the first run and uploads it to keyspace '1000'. When i edit it and re-run with 1001, the script attempts to destroy previously created file in test/prod/1000/keys. All i'm looking to do is

- Import existing table state without recreating it
- Add folders to keyspaces, without touching previous contents of table.

Comment: You're probably not using terraform correctly. The Terraform configuration language is declarative. It describes the state in which your infrastructure should be in. It maintains a state of all objects that have been created and removes those that are not in described anymore (like your files in /test/prod/1000/keys). I would suggest to use other means of moving the files to the s3 bucket. Simplest would be a bash script imho.

Answer (score 0):

**The result you are getting is what is expected from Terraform.**

TF maintains "the state" of the infrastructure in *.tfstate* files. They are a mirror image of what the infrastructure was last time they were synced.

The desired state of the infrastructure is described in *.tf* files.

Running `terraform plan` or `terraform apply` commands compares *.tf* and *.tfstate* files. Then, **any resources that are present in *.tfstate* and not in *.tf* are destroyed**.

In your case, it has *keyspace 1000* in *.tfstate* from the previous run, but not in the *.tf* because you edited it to *1001*.

### The ways around it

1. **Use AWS CLI**, as suggested in the comment by Winston
2. **Add another resource** for keyspace 1001 instead of editing the one you have

---

Also, I noticed that you have

```
source = "deploy"
etag = "${md5(file("keys"))}"
```

Usually, they should refer to the same file:

```
source = "readme.md"
etag = "${filemd5("readme.md")}"
```